# Outlook search not working

Tags: ms-office, monterey, exchange, microsoft

My Outlook search stopped working. There are no results for any query. There are a few suggestions online. None of them seem to work. I tried:

- forcing repair of database by deleting `Outlook.sqllite`
- turning Spotlight on and off (`sudo mdutil -i on /`)
- adding and removing the Main Profile folder from the list of locations that Spotlight is prevented from searching

Is there anything else I could try?

I am running Outlook 16.56 and 16.57 on macOS 12.1.

Update: I found [a discussion that suggests this may be an issue with Monterey 12.1](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/monterey-12-1-update-broke-my-outlook-365-search-function.2327507/) and [another one on Apple Developer forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/694230). It seems that updating to 16.57 worked for some people there, but it did not for me.

Comment: Did you ever try this in the Terminal?
mdimport -r /Applications/Microsoft\ Outlook.app/Contents/Library/Spotlight/Microsoft\ Outlook\ Spotlight\ Importer.mdimporter

Comment: Yes, I tried that too.

Answer (score 1):

A colleague of mine was affected by this issue after migrating to a new MacBook Pro (2021) running macOS 12.4 (using a Time Machine Backup of his previous MacBook Pro running Big Sur). The Outlook version was 16.61.

My first attempts at rebuilding the Spotlight index using Onyx did not bring back search in Outlook, but with the following sequence of Terminal commands (taken from page 17 of the Mac Rumors thread you found) I was able to fix the issue on his Mac. To be on the safe side, I waited 15s after running each of the `mdutil` commands.

Here are the commands you need to copy & paste to Terminal:

- `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist`  (there's a good chance that this step is not necessary, but I did it anyway, just in case)
- `sudo mdutil -Eai off`
- `sudo mdutil -Eai on`
- `mdutil -as`

After running these commands, the Mac took significantly longer to recreate the Spotlight index than it did after I used Onyx. At some point during this process, Outlook would start to slowly show more and more search results.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved, but there is a catch here,
I had the same problem, went through all the steps, and the issue was resolved for a few minutes, then the pain returned!

After many tries and waiting for results, I found conflict software, like a torrent, that looks to make conflicts in indexing; I deleted it, and then all issues about the search were resolved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).